# iOS 7 Pull-to-refresh twitch

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I encountered a problem in iOS 7 with an element UIRefreshControl.

If you pull down the *UITableView* and hold it (will not let go of your finger) the *UIRefreshControl* starts to rotate, and then when *UIRefreshControl* get the message *endRefreshing*, it will begin to twitch.

As I understand it, he repeatedly tries to play an animation.

You can see this effect in the standard Mail application .

Any idea how to fix this bug?

Comment: On 7.0.2 the pull to refresh in mail has no twitch, glitch or other bug that I can see. If you're seeing it throughout the device, I'd recommend wiping your device, or filing a RADAR with Apple.